# Rails partial stacktrace in logs, having shared code outside of /app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, production

I have 2 rails applications (one is the admin, the other implements a http api) that share some code (models,serializers..) as a git submodule, outside of /app. The submodule is rooted in /shared.

The error log contains the stacktrace entries that match ^app/, so I get a partial (often useless) stacktrace.

Is there a way to configure what gets logged, so that I get a meaningful stacktrace?

PS.: In development, I can look in the 'Full Trace' tab and see the full stacktrace, but in production, the logs only include ^app/ matching entries.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Added the lines below to **/config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb**

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line !~ /app|shared/ }
```

Now the stacktrace has both **app** and **shared** entries included. Yey!